# Not able to create csv file using python csv.writer

Tags: python, csv, xml-parsing

I have to use below code to get my actual data form sharepoint xml.
I am able to get the data as required,but not able to write in csv file with csv.writer.
Data is coming in single column instead of two.Kindly suggest

```
from lxml import etree

xml_tree = etree.parse("file.xml")

data_nodes = xml_tree.findall("//{#RowsetSchema}row")

for node in data_nodes:
    print node.get('Title'), node.get("dept")
```

here I am passing data after opening csv file as

```
data ='{},{}'.format(node.get('Title'), node.get("dept"))
writer.writerow(data)
```

But data is comming with double quotes and showing in single column instead of two column.I need data should go for "Title" in one column and for "dept" in another column

Comment: `data` should be a list, not a string.

Comment: `data = [node.get('Title'), node.get('dept')]`

Comment: but in linux concole data is showing correctly,I want this print statement data to be insert in csv file

Comment: The whole point of the `csv` module is that it will convert a list into a comma-separated line in the file. You don't need to format it yourself.

Comment: @Barmar Perfect sir Thank you very much,i badly needed this !!!!!!!!!!!